# React Router onEnter Function "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am checking for a config value to be set, if it is I want to redirect to a child route. if not just display as usual. The code does update the URL as expected but then gets into an infinite loop.

`index.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router'
import App from './modules/App'
import About from './modules/About'
import Map from './modules/Map'
import Maps from './modules/Maps'
import Home from './modules/Home'
import { settings } from './appconfig.js';

function checkDefaultFloor(){
  if (settings.floorUrl){
    console.log( settings.floorUrl);
     browserHistory.push('/maps/'+ settings.floorUrl);
  }
}

render((
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/maps" component={Maps}  onEnter={checkDefaultFloor}>
        <Route path="/maps/:mapName" component={Map}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('app'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes into an infinite loop, because each time you enter the route `/maps` `checkDefaultFloor()` is executed which redirects to one of `/map's` children.

The redirect triggers `onEnter -> checkDefaultFloor()` once again, hence endless recursion.

What you need to do is either move the functionality in `componentDidMount` of `<Maps />` or check if you haven't already redirected, for instance

```
hasRedirected = false;

function checkDefaultFloor(){
  if (settings.floorUrl && !hasRedirected) {
    hasRedirected = true;
    browserHistory.push('/maps/'+ settings.floorUrl);
  }
}
```

Comment: >> move the functionality in componentDidMount of <Maps />--
worked for me

Comment: have a look at the other answer with replace, I like it better if it works

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. The solution was to implement what Shubham Khatri, suggested. However, an important point I originally missed was to attach the onEnter callback to an IndexRoute. I'm using standard JavaScript objects to define my routes. This is what I needed to do:

```js
{
  path: '/',
  indexRoute: {
    onEnter: (nextState, replace) => replace('some-route')
  },
  childRoutes: [...]
}
```

I would bet that there was a similar problem with the OP's JSX code. It likely should have been like this (although I haven't tested this):

```js
function checkDefaultFloor(nextState, replace, callback){
  if (settings.floorUrl){
    console.log( settings.floorUrl);
    replace(`/maps/${settings.floorUrl}`)
  }
  callback();
}
```

```js
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/maps" component={Maps}>
        <IndexRoute onEnter={checkDefaultFloor}/>
        <Route path="/maps/:mapName" component={Map}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

You `browserHistory.push()` statement is making it to go in an endless loop since the route is nested insided your `map` route. You need to make use of `replace` function and `callback` like.

```
function checkDefaultFloor(nextState, replace, callback){
  if (settings.floorUrl){
    console.log( settings.floorUrl);
     replace(`/maps/${settings.floorUrl}`)
  }
  callback();
}
```

Comment: I think this answer might be better, are you sure that replace doesn't trigger onEnter again?

Comment: Replace is used for the very purpose